# Downcasting/upcasting via void*

Tags: c++, casting

I have a class hierarchy that involves virtual functions, multiple inheritance, but not virtual inheritance. The whole hierarchy roots in a base class `B`. A class appears at most in the hierarchy.

Now, I am using a library where I can only pass and receive back `void*` (some “handles” basically).

In which circumstances is it safe/legal/defined to cast between instances of my hierarchy and `void*`?

Should I always upcast to `B*` before passing `void*` and vice versa?

Will `(D*) (B*) (void*) (B*) d` be equal to `d` if `d` is an instance of `D*` and `D` a subclass of `B`?

Comment: Depends. With multiple inheritance and no virtual inheritance then, if  `B` is inherited from multiple times (for example, via two bases of a derived class), "upcasting" to `B *` is ambiguous.    If no class inherits from `B` more than once (via other classes), then the "upcast" is safe.   You also need to consider the problem of "downcasting", if you need to get back to the original (actual) class (e.g. if a derived class provides a member function that is not part of `B`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must cast from `void*` to the same exact type you cast to `void*` to begin with. This is guaranteed to be safe. Other casts from `void*` lead to UB.

Once you have a non-void pointer, normal casting rules for pointers of a class hierarchy apply.

Using your example,

```
(D*) (B*) (void*) (B*) d
```

is OK, but

```
(D*) (void*) (B*) d
(B*) (void*) d
```

are not.